# Can I use Django debug toolbar with Postman

Tags: postman, django-debug-toolbar

I'm using postman for APIs request

Now I want to check that if there's any N+1 query on my API
I've installed Django Debug Toolbar through this guide https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html but don't know how to trigger the panel on API call through Postman, my backend server run on docker port 8000

Thank you for your advance